# Ohm's Law calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm looking for ways to make this calculator more efficient and/or make the code a little easier to read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;



// variables to be used in the program
double result, valueA, valueB, valA, valB;
int choice;
char cont;

//functions to perform the calculations

double mult(double valueA, double valueB) {
result = valueA * valueB;
return result;
}

double div(double valueA, double valueB) {
result = valueA / valueB;
return result;
}



// functions that prompt the user for values to be calculated


double getValueA(string unit) {
cout << "Enter " << unit << ": " << endl;
cin >> valA;
cout << endl;
return valA;
}

double getValueB(string unit) {
cout << "Enter " << unit << ": " << endl;
cin >> valB;
cout << endl;
return valB;
}



void title() {
cout << "**** NEO-VOLT ELECTRICAL CALCULATOR ****" << endl;
cout << "*   by *" << endl;
cout << "*Adam Pate *" << endl;
cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << endl << endl << endl;
}

void showMenu() {
cout << " Main Menu: " << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Ohm's Law" << endl;
cout << " 1. Voltage " << endl;
cout << " 2. Resistance " << endl;
cout << " 3. Current " << endl;
cout << "Power Law" << endl;
cout << " 4. Wattage " << endl;
cout << " 5. Voltage " << endl;
cout << " 6. Current " << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << " 0. Exit the program " << endl;



}
//Shows results of the calculation
void displayResult(string units) {
cout << result << " " << units;
cout << endl << endl;

}
// Takes the users choice and calls functions accordingly
void processMenu() {
cin >> choice;
switch(choice) {
case 0:
exit(0);
case 1:
getValueA("Amps");
getValueB("Ohms");
mult(valA, valB);
displayResult("Volts");
break;
case 2:
getValueA("Volts");
getValueB("Amps");
div(valA, valB);
displayResult("Ohms");
break;
case 3:
getValueA("Volts");
getValueB("Ohms");
div(valA, valB);
displayResult("Amps");
break;
case 4:
getValueA("Volts");
getValueB("Amps");
mult(valA, valB);
displayResult("Watts");
break;
case 5:
getValueA("Watts");
getValueB("Amps");
div(valA, valB);
displayResult("Volts");
break;
case 6:
getValueA("Watts");
getValueB("Volts");
div(valA, valB);
displayResult("Amps");
break;
default:
cout << "Invalid choice.";
}

}




int main()
{
title();
do {
showMenu();
processMenu();
cout << "Perform another calculation? (y or n)" << endl;
cin >> cont;
} while(cont != 'n');


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Indent your code.
- There is no need to define functions for multiplication and division. It is just as clear to say `a * b` as `mult(a,b)`.
- `getValueA` and `getValueB` do exactly the same thing, except with a different global. The return value of these functions is ignored. It would be better to merge these into one and use the return value.
- Don't use `valA` and `valB` for variable names. Use local variables with names like `volt`.
- Don't use a global for the result. Pass it as a parameter to `displayResult`, like this:

  ```
  case 1:
      double amps = getValue("Amps");
      double ohms = getValue("Ohms");
      displayResult(amps * ohms, "volts");
  ```
- You can, and should, avoid global variables completely here, as `valueA` and `valueB` are never used in the global context, they can be removed.
- If the user types "no" or "N" it is treated as Yes. Handle this more carefully. For example, consider only the lowercase of the first letter.